# Как правильно сделать SELECT из таблицы?

Tags: mysql, sql, select, запрос

Есть таблица (структура как на скриншоте), где

- `id` - уникальный идентификатор записи,
- `text` - текст строки,
- `aid` - идентификатор, обозначающий принадлежность строки, по которому я связываюсь с другой таблицей,
- `user` - идентификатор пользователя, также для связи с другой таблицей.

Как сделать из неё такую выборку: нужно выбрать из неё все строки по полю `aid`, при условии, что нужно выбрать только те строки по `aid`, которые содержат и текст "asd" и текст "fgh"? В итоге должны быть выбраны `aid`: 1,2,6.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: вам не подходит like ?

Comment: К чему именно не подходит? Сейчас я не имею самого запроса, чтобы  понимать, где использовать LIKE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно так:

```
SELECT aid FROM table 
  WHERE text="asd" AND aid IN(SELECT aid FROM table WHERE text="fgh")
  GROUP BY aid
```

Вариант не очень, конечно, но работать будет

Comment: Ваш вариант отдает другое количество строк (имеется в виду из рабочей таблицы, не из примера). Всего в таблице 100 000 строк, разница около 2 тысяч с результатом запроса из комментария выше.

Comment: @ultrabatya, запрос из комментария выше не подходит для вашего случая.

Comment: Спасибо, работает так, как требуется.

Answer (score 1):

Можно так:

```
select aid from tbl
  where text = "asd" or text = "fgh"
  group by aid
  having count(distinct text) = 2
```

Возвращает эти результати:

```
aid
---
 1
 2
 6
```

[Демо на SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8d7a6/16/0)

Comment: Спасибо, этот вариант работает, но выбрал другой вариант из предложенных!

Answer (score 0):

```
select aid from table where text="asd" or text="fgh" group by aid
```

Нужно ли разжевать?

Comment: Наверное, нет. Но хочу уточнить, почему в WHERE используется OR, а не AND? Нужно, чтобы оба условия одновременно соблюдались.

Comment: OR - если поиск по одному полю. AND - если по разным. Так как он будет искать и то, и другое одновременно. то есть результата не будет.